# Current state of WiX 4

Tags: wix

I'm new to WiX and I'm wondering if I should start with WiX 3 or 4. WiX 3 is the current stable version but WiX 4 brings many new features. Should I wait for stable version 4 and stick with 3 for now or go with 4 right away?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45515120/what-is-the-state-of-wix-v4