# What is the state of WiX v4?

Tags: wix

I really feel like I shouldn't have to ask a question on SO to get basic information like this, but I can't find a reliable source anywhere.

Is WiX v4 released? In Development? In Beta? Still being designed?

Lots of people seem to already be using WiX v4, as evidenced by SO questions about it. And it has an official release page on the WiX site, without any mention of "Beta" or "Release Candidate", etc: http://wixtoolset.org/releases/v4-0-0-5205/

However, there are no released versions for v4 on GitHub: https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix4/releases

And the Wix homepage still directs you to download v3.

And one of the developer's blogs has a [recent post about v4](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2017/07/11/proposed-platform-support-in-wix-v4-0/) that uses future-tense language like "will have" and "should support".

But worst of all, the *current version* of the WiX visual studio integration tools has templates for v4, which makes it seem like v4 is officially supported!

And when you try to build one of these templates the build error is `The WiX Toolset v4 build tools must be installed ... To download WiX Toolset v4, see http://wixtoolset.org/releases/` despite the fact that http://wixtoolset.org/releases/ contains downloads exclusively for v3!

This is a crazy amount of mixed messages.

Is there something somewhere that says **officially, definitively** what state WiX v4 is in?

Comment: I think you have pretty much answered your own question. WiX 4 is not released as far as I know - although it has been 8 years already since version 3. Time flies, and I am sure WiX 4 will be a great toolkit once released. WiX 3.11 was recently released on May 5th.2017.

Comment: As of today, there hasn't been a weekly release of v4 since November of 2017.  There hasn't been a commit to the GitHub repos since May 3, 2018.   That doesn't mean things aren't happening and it also doesn't mean things will happen soon.   For 99% of people the answer is adopt Wix 3.11 and start coding.   If you want to help develop WiX then join the wix-devs mailing list and ask about v4 and how you can help.   I am curious to see where v4 goes but I'm firmly on v3 until then.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The previous answer is out dated. WiX v4 is very close to being ready and I encourage active testing of it during the RC phase.

In WiX v4, there is no installer for WiX.  It's a dotnet tool you install.  If your a user of Votive, Votive is no more.  Instead FireGiant has a closed source but free replacement called HeatWave.  This creates your .wixproj which is now an SDK style project. References to extensions are no longer DLL references but Nuget package references.

There is a tool to covnvert v3 schema to v4 schema called WiXCop.  Heatwave will do this for you in a one time project by project conversion step.

WiX is no longer installed on the build server as msbuild will automatically install the SDK package references.

FireGiant reached out to be before the release and gave me a preview look. From this I was able to update my open source project IsWiX to completely support v3 or v4 using Votive or HeatWave.

All in all it's looking really good and once all the final bugs are gone I will be migrating all of my customers over to WiX v4.

Comment: This answer is out dated.  WiX v4 is very close to being ready and I encourage active testing of it during the RC phase.

Comment: I'm a new WIX user and I'm more than happy to test it out, but I can't find any docs about v4.

Comment: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/intro/

Comment: Have you read that? It looks not a docs, just some simple description. It doesn't say at all how to build an msi.

Comment: If you are new to WiX, v3 is the better place to start. I have an open source project with tutorials that will help get you started. https://github.com/wixtoolset/web Consulting/training is available for a fee.  As for the WiXToolSet docs, it is an open source project and PRs are accepted at https://github.com/wixtoolset/web

Comment: @ChristopherPainter, yes, there is a PLACEHOLDER for documentation found at the link you posted above, but it is so scant, it's useless.

Answer (score 13):

[WiX Toolset v4](https://www.firegiant.com/blog/2023/4/5/wix-v4-and-heatwave-v1-released/) was released on April 5, 2023. There are regular updates on the [FireGiant blog](https://www.firegiant.com/blog/) that are helpful for tracking continuing progress on the toolset. WiX v4 is now a [.NET tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools). This release contains many significant changes from v3.

Answer (score 6):

WiX v4 does appear as a number of weekly releases which can be downloaded and installed. I've installed v4.0.0.5918, and it appears to work with the integrated Visual Studio WiX extension v4 projects, though I've not tested this extensively. The wxs project template looks identical to v3.

Considering the progress of v4, although I admit I'm quite new to this, I found a page here going back as far as end 2012!
http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2012/12/12/the-wix-toolset-v4.0-begins/

A more recent article on WiX v4.0 and it's features can be found here
https://www.joyofsetup.com/tag/wix4/

Bug fix logs also imply v4 is being developed alongside v3, however indeed without formal confirmation, official releases, or any documentation whatsoever.
https://www.firegiant.com/blog/2015/6/2/wix-online-meeting-68-highlights/
https://www.firegiant.com/blog/2017/7/11/wix-online-meeting-130-highlights/

**UPDATE**

WiX v4 (preview) has just been released, for more information see the main page:

https://wixtoolset.org/docs/releasenotes/
https://wixtoolset.org/docs/intro/